# Calculate the intersection (x,y) between f(x) and g(x), in limits range a and b

Tags: python, lambda, intersection

Input (from file):

```
x^2-x+2,
x^3-1,
-2 2
```

Desired output:

```
intersection: (1.5747,2.9051)
```

I need to calculate the x,y coordinate intersection between two math functions using Newton Rephson algorithm, first, I input from the file then use `func_sum` to calculate the two function `f` and `g`, and send `h` function (res of `f` and `g`) to the `NR` function to find the root. I'm not sure if I'm doing it right, I'm trying to find a solution.

```
import random

def diff(f):
    ''' returns the numeric derivative of f '''
    h = 0.000001
    return (lambda x: (f(x+h)-f(x))/h)

def NR(f, epsilon=10**(-10), n=100):
    ''' finds an approximation to a root of
    f using the Newton Raphson method '''
    deriv = diff(f)
    x0 = random.uniform(-10, 10)
    while (abs(deriv(x0))<epsilon):
        x0 = random.uniform(-10, 10)
    x=x0; y=f(x); count=1
    print("{0}. x={1}, f(x)={2}".format(count,x,y))
    while(abs(y) > epsilon and count <= n):
        count += 1
        y=f(x)
        x = x - y/deriv(x)
        print("{0}. x={1}, f(x)={2}".format(count,x,y))
    if count > n:
        return None
    return (lambda a,b : x in range(a,b))

def func_sum(f_Func, g_Func):
    ''' function calculate the sum of f and g '''
    def h(x):
        return f_Func(x) + g_Func(x)
    return h

def main():
    f=open('input.txt','r')
    line=f.read().split('\n')
    f_Func = eval('lambda x:'+ line[0]) # f(x)
    g_Func = eval('lambda x:'+ line[1]) # g(x)
    h_Func = func_sum(f_Func,g_Func)
    # f(h) = f(x)+ g(x)
    limts = line[2].split()
    a = int(limts[0]) ; b = int(limts[1]) # a b are limits
    print('intersection: ', NR(h_Func)(a,b))

main()
```

Comment: In Python, the exponent is written as ``x**2``, so you should write ``x**2 - x + 2,
x**3 - 2``. Do you want to compute the derivative manually? You can use https://github.com/google/jax or https://github.com/HIPS/autograd. Also, do you want to write the method by yourself? You could use https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.newton.html#scipy.optimize.newton